# Group PostgreSQL data to have no more than N values in output

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping, aggregate-functions

I need to load chart data fast. The data resides in a date-Y table:

```
CREATE TABLE (
    id serial primary key,
    date timestamp not null,
    y1 double precision,
    y2 double precision,
    y3 double precision,
    y4 double precision,
    ....................
    yN double precision
);
```

To simplify this question lets say I load date (X axis) and Y1 (Y axis) only.

Chart contains horizontally N points and has variable zooming. X axis contains points from mindate to maxdate. Values of mindate and maxdate depend on current scaling and panning position.

In order to load data fast I need to perform dynamic data grouping by using any aggregate function (MIN, MAX, AVG) so that I get no more than N aggregated records in a range from mindate to maxdate.

The data should be grouped in equal time intervals, i.e. each 5 seconds, each 3 minutes, depending on current chart scale.

How to achieve this with PostgreSQL?

**Samples**

```
select date, "1_2_pt100_x_1" from ob_data where "1_2_pt100_x_1" is not null order by date
```

13414 records:

```
"2016-12-08 12:13:41";44.5
"2016-12-08 12:16:42";44.7000007629395
"2016-12-08 12:19:43";44.9000015258789
"2016-12-08 12:22:44";45.2999992370606
"2016-12-08 12:25:44";45.5
"2016-12-08 12:30:11";45.9000015258789
"2016-12-08 12:33:12";45.5999984741211
"2016-12-08 12:36:12";45.9000015258789
"2016-12-08 12:39:13";46.2000007629395
"2016-12-08 12:42:14";46.5
"2016-12-08 12:45:15";46.5999984741211
"2016-12-08 12:48:15";46.9000015258789
"2016-12-08 12:51:16";47
"2016-12-08 12:54:16";47.0999984741211
"2016-12-08 12:57:17";47.4000015258789
"2016-12-08 13:00:17";47.4000015258789
"2016-12-08 13:03:18";47.7000007629395
"2016-12-08 13:06:18";47.7999992370606
"2016-12-08 13:09:19";47.7999992370606
"2016-12-08 13:12:19";47.7999992370606
"2016-12-08 13:15:20";48.0999984741211
"2016-12-08 13:18:20";48.0999984741211
"2016-12-08 13:21:21";48
"2016-12-08 13:24:21";48.4000015258789
"2016-12-08 13:27:22";48.2999992370606
"2016-12-08 13:30:22";48.2000007629395
"2016-12-09 08:58:54";20.2999992370606
"2016-12-09 09:01:55";20.3999996185303
"2016-12-09 09:04:55";20.6000003814697
"2016-12-09 09:07:56";20.6000003814697
"2016-12-09 09:10:56";20.8999996185303
"2016-12-09 09:13:57";20.7000007629395
"2016-12-09 09:16:57";21.2999992370606
"2016-12-09 09:19:58";21.5
"2016-12-09 09:22:58";22
"2016-12-09 09:25:59";22.2000007629395
"2016-12-09 09:28:59";22.5
"2016-12-09 09:32:00";22.8999996185303
"2016-12-09 09:35:00";23.1000003814697
"2016-12-09 09:38:01";23.2999992370606
"2016-12-09 09:41:01";23.6000003814697
"2016-12-09 09:44:02";24.1000003814697
"2016-12-09 09:47:02";24.2999992370606
"2016-12-09 09:50:03";24.6000003814697
"2016-12-09 09:53:03";24.7999992370606
"2016-12-09 09:56:04";25.2000007629395
"2016-12-09 09:59:04";25.2999992370606
"2016-12-09 10:02:05";25.7000007629395
"2016-12-09 10:05:05";25.8999996185303
"2016-12-09 10:08:06";25.8999996185303
"2016-12-09 10:11:06";26.2999992370606
"2016-12-09 10:14:07";26.3999996185303
"2016-12-09 10:17:07";26.7999992370606
```

**Expected output**

for the first 6 lines, scaling factor 2, using average function:

```
"2016-12-08 12:13:41";44,6000003814698
"2016-12-08 12:19:43";45,1000003814698
"2016-12-08 12:25:44";45,7000007629395
```

(I calculated it by myself using a calculator, so don't ask me for corresponding SQL query).

Taking 2 lines for each aggregate result isn't actually the right way. The whole data space between mindate and maxdate should be split into N equal intervals and each interval should be aggregated. As an aggregate value for date I should take the first date of each interval.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imported your data:

```
create table so6 (d timestamp,f float);
copy so6 from stdin delimiter ',';
```

Here `ntile(27)` means you have to devide 53 by 2 to get 27 - if you want to aggregate rows each two, if you want each five, it would be ntile(11):

```
with p as (
         select *, ntile(27) over(order by d) n
         from so6
         order by d
) select distinct min(d) over (partition by n),
         avg(f) over (partition by n)
from p
order by min;

         min         |       avg
---------------------+------------------
 2016-12-08 12:13:41 | 44.6000003814698
 2016-12-08 12:19:43 | 45.1000003814697
 2016-12-08 12:25:44 | 45.7000007629395
 2016-12-08 12:33:12 |            45.75
 2016-12-08 12:39:13 | 46.3500003814698
 2016-12-08 12:45:15 |            46.75
 2016-12-08 12:51:16 | 47.0499992370605
 2016-12-08 12:57:17 | 47.4000015258789
 2016-12-08 13:03:18 |            47.75
 2016-12-08 13:09:19 | 47.7999992370606
 2016-12-08 13:15:20 | 48.0999984741211
 2016-12-08 13:21:21 | 48.2000007629395
 2016-12-08 13:27:22 |            48.25
 2016-12-09 08:58:54 | 20.3499994277954
 2016-12-09 09:04:55 | 20.6000003814697
 2016-12-09 09:10:56 | 20.8000001907349
 2016-12-09 09:16:57 | 21.3999996185303
 2016-12-09 09:22:58 | 22.1000003814697
 2016-12-09 09:28:59 | 22.6999998092652
 2016-12-09 09:35:00 | 23.1999998092652
 2016-12-09 09:41:01 | 23.8500003814697
 2016-12-09 09:47:02 | 24.4499998092652
 2016-12-09 09:53:03 |               25
 2016-12-09 09:59:04 |             25.5
 2016-12-09 10:05:05 | 25.8999996185303
 2016-12-09 10:11:06 | 26.3499994277954
 2016-12-09 10:17:07 | 26.7999992370606
(27 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually I don't fully understand how it works, but it works. Is it possible to do an automatic AVG for all the data columns except "d" regardless of how much columns have been added to the table? (an equivalent to SELECT *)

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand :) It's is hard to see what you want, unless you put sample data as you did for your initial question

Comment: I mean that a SELECT * FROM query doesn't require to mention all the fields, but for an aggregate query there is probably no equivalent.

Comment: well - when you aggregate, you do it around some columns, so you have to specify them